# Calculate and Plot Timing Jitter from Power Spectral Density

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-analysis, phase

I have the Power Spectral Density and I need to calculate and plot the Timing Jitter with python. I was surprised that I couldn't find any functions or similar scripts of this online, the only thing I could find was methods for finding the total timing jitter.
Does such a function/method exist?

For reference the data I am trying to plot is [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_viQkcWo4Z2QWFOOEJpUk5tRm8/view?usp=sharing) with frequency in the first column and PSD in the second